# Group by foreach bug

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have foreach loop in Razor that iterates over `group by`-ed elements so every element must have a Key property but it throws me Exception :

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key'
```

[image: WAT]

Comment: As far as I am aware, ViewBag is dynamic, and all variables in the ViewBag are resolved at runtime. Then again, I might be on crack.

Comment: @tranceporter No that sounds about right.

Comment: Please post the code that is populating the `Links` member.

Comment: Why do you want to declare `g` as dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing your loop to

```
foreach(IGrouping<T1, T2> g in ViewBag.Links)
{
    ...
}
```

substituting in the actual types of your grouping key and value.